# Webpack + Electron: Why I need "electron-renderer" script if application work without it?

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron

Below webpack config does not include `{ target: electron-renderer }`, only `electron-main` settings.

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  return {
      name: 'Electron: main process',
      target: 'electron-main',

      context,
      entry: {
        'InitializeProject_GUI': './InitializeProject_GUI.ts',
      },

      output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: '[name].js'
      },

      node: {
        __dirname: false,
        __filename: false
      },

      // ...
    }
};
```

Nevertheless, the command `election InitializeProject_GUI.js` starts my application:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>My app</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

### InitializeProject_GUI.ts (Source code: TypeScript)

```js
import URL from 'url';
import Path from 'path';

import {
  app as electronApplication,
  App as ElectronApplication,
  BrowserWindow
} from 'electron';
import enableElectronDebug from 'electron-debug';

class ProjectInitializer {

  private electronApplication: ElectronApplication;
  private mainWindow: BrowserWindow | null = null;

  private static SOURCE_FILES_DIRECTORY_RELATIVE_PATH: string = 'Source';
  private static MARKUP_AND_STYLES_DIRECTORY_RELATIVE_PATH: string = 'GUI';
  private static MAIN_WINDOW_MARKUP__FILE_NAME_WITH_EXTENSION: string = 'MainWindow.html';

  private constructor() {

    this.electronApplication = electronApplication;

    enableElectronDebug();

    this.electronApplication.on('ready', this.onApplicationReadyEventHandler.bind(this));
  }

  public static start(): void {
    const projectInitializer: ProjectInitializer = new ProjectInitializer();
  }

  private onApplicationReadyEventHandler(): void {

    this.mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 640,
      height: 500,
      titleBarStyle: 'hidden'
    });

    this.mainWindow.loadURL(URL.format({
      pathname: Path.join(
          __dirname,
          ProjectInitializer.SOURCE_FILES_DIRECTORY_RELATIVE_PATH,
          ProjectInitializer.MARKUP_AND_STYLES_DIRECTORY_RELATIVE_PATH,
          ProjectInitializer.MAIN_WINDOW_MARKUP__FILE_NAME_WITH_EXTENSION
      ),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
    }));

    this.mainWindow.setMenu(null);
  }
}

(function executeApplication(): void {
  ProjectInitializer.start();
})();
```

Why my application works without renderer (`{ target: electron-renderer }`) script file?

Comment: I wrote an answer, but deleted it as I'm not really sure about it. What happens if you try to use `fs` in the renderer process, without specifying "electron-renderer" as target ?

Comment: @Seblor, at least, application will not crash...

Comment: The app may not crash, but you might not be able to use most native modules.

Comment: @Seblor, To use this modules, I need `{ target: electron-renderer }` preset?

Comment: I think so. But since I'm not sure, I would like to know what happens if you try to use `fs` in the renderer process without this preset.